# Lock edges in their original position

Tags: modeling

These two models are parts of LOD files:

[image: Two models]

I want to shrink one of them down (*lodcutw09*) and this is a selection that I want to shrink down a little bit:

[image: Selection to shrink]

The problem is, when I use the shrink tool on that selection, it also moves position of the edges:

[image: Shrink tool causes moving edges]

Is it possible to lock all the edges in their original place so they won't change their position at all? Because if they do, they form small holes in the map. Or maybe there is a different way of doing this?

Comment: The question is not formed well enough. It's unlikely that you can receive meaningful help with your problem with formulation like this. Edit the question and communicate your problem better. Add more images and descriptions that could let us know what your goal is, also explain how you attempt to "shrink" the model. If you make a screenshot, do not cut parts of it off, so people can see your settings. It might be Proportional editing, that might be causing parts that are close to selected ones move as well, but we cannot see if it's enabled.

Comment: You've probably got duplicate vertices there. Try removing doubles first.

Answer (score 0):

Deselecting all bottom vertices solved the issue!

[image: Vertices]